# Condensing/combining multiple columns with same name and logical values

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, combinations, multiple-columns

I am trying to condense a `data.frame` that has the same column multiple times. Columns to be condensed have logical values.

The `data.frame` looks like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame (ID = c("1A", "2A", "3A", "1B", "2B", "3B"),
                A = c("N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5", "N6"),
                AA = c(T, T, F, F, F, F),
                BB = c(T, T, F, F, F, F),
                AA = c(T, F, T, F, F, F),
                CC = c(T, F, T, F, T, F),
                DD = c(T, F, T, F, T, T),
                AA = c(F, F, F, F, T, F),
                EE = c(F, F, T, T, T, F),
                AA = c(F, F, F, F, F, F), check.names = FALSE)
```

I want to condense `AA` in a way that the condense column is set to `TRUE` if all the `AA` columns in one row are set to `TRUE` a least once. For example, in row `1A` the `AA` columns have a sequence of `TRUE`, `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `FALSE`. This means the condense column, lets call it ZZ, should have `TRUE` in row `1A` but `FALSE` in row `3B`.

The desired output looks like this:

```
mydfnew <- data.frame (ID = c("1A", "2A", "3A", "1B", "2B", "3B"),
                A = c("N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5", "N6"),
                AA = c(T, T, T, F, T, F),
                BB = c(T, T, F, F, F, F),
                CC = c(T, F, T, F, T, F),
                DD = c(T, F, T, F, T, T),
                EE = c(F, F, T, T, T, F))
```

The `AA` columns are replace by the condensed `ZZ` column which is once again called AA. I do now know how the AA columns are called and there are multiple of such "duplicate" columns. I hope this makes sense.

Any help and pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ding ding ding!

```
l <- sapply(df, is.logical)

cbind(df[!l], lapply(split(as.list(df[l]), names(df)[l]), Reduce, f = `|`))
```

Comment: It eludes me how this can be so easy but it worked on my `data.frame` with 10.000 columns. I have taken this as my accepted answer for its simplicity and efficiency.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

A solution for all columns (except the first two):

```
res <- tapply(names(mydf)[-(1:2)], names(mydf)[-(1:2)], FUN = function(n)
        as.logical(rowSums(mydf[names(mydf) %in% n[1]]))) 

cbind(mydf[1:2], do.call(cbind, res))


  ID  A    AA    BB    CC    DD    EE
1 1A N1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2 2A N2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 3A N3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
4 1B N4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
5 2B N5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
6 3B N6 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Works perfectly on my data as the first columns are identifying columns.

Answer (score 1):

As a start:

```
rowSums(mydf[,colnames(mydf) == 'AA']) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially a variation on @SvenHohenstein's solution:

```
unq <- unique(names(mydf)[-(1:2)])
res <- setNames(lapply(unq, function(x) rowSums(mydf[names(mydf)==x])>0 ),unq)
cbind(mydf[1:2],res)

#  ID  A    AA    BB    CC    DD    EE
#1 1A N1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#2 2A N2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 3A N3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#4 1B N4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#5 2B N5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#6 3B N6 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was going to be real straightforward, but it turns out `melt` doesn't do great when you have repeated column names, so this gets a bit finicky:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
df.names <- names(mydf)
var.names <- paste0("V", 1:(length(df.names) - 2))
real.names <- df.names[-(1:2)]
names(mydf) <- c(df.names[1:2], var.names)
dt <- data.table(melt(mydf, id.vars=c("ID", "A")))
dt[, variable:=real.names[match(variable, var.names)]]
dcast(
  dt[, list(value=any(value)), by=list(ID, A, variable)], 
  ID + A ~ variable
)
#   ID  A    AA    BB    CC    DD    EE
# 1 1A N1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2 1B N4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 3 2A N2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 4 2B N5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# 5 3A N3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# 6 3B N6 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Note result set is not in exact same order as yours, but it should be easy to re-order if it matters.  Note I think `N4` is wrong in your desired output.

Comment: Yes, you are right `N4` had the wrong desired result. I have edited it in the question.